# Symfony 2.7 in local & server without port and without run server command?

Tags: php, symfony

some conceptual questions:

1. how do I publish to my local (or in my VPS) with virtualhost
   apache2 without having to place the port (8000) and
2. how I do not have to run the php command: php app/console
   server:run, every time, to make it a service that is always running

sure this is silly but I can not understand this, Greetings

Comment: I've deployed many `Symfony2` apps without having to place the port `8000` nor having to run the command `$ php app/console server:run`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: look the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html,  $ cd my_project_name/
$ php app/console server:run Then, open your browser and access the http://localhost:8000/app/example URL to see the Welcome page of Symfony:   if only create my virtualhost in apache, the app not work

Comment: Questions in a better way: What is the procedure to install my app symfony 2.7 in ubuntu VPS with a domain for example www.myapp.com

Comment: Weird, I usually go with a simple [`$ php composer.phar create-project`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#creating-a-symfony-application-with-composer) composer command.

Comment: No men, for 2.7 the documentation no have that instructions, with this command create a proyect: # $ symfony new my_project_name and them with this command run the app with a port: php app/console server:run, the app will be available through http://localhost:8000/app/example, I want to have my app as when you installed a wordpress, without any commands to access it using a url, I think this is something new from sf2.6 or 2.7, I have been far from sf since 2012 and version 2.1

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you develop your app using built in php webserver, and want to deploy your app to real websever(apache2) ? You probably can do these:

1. Your app will normally have these folder: web, app, src, vendor
2. Upload all of those folder to DocumentRoot of your server (usually named `var/www` or `public_html`) lets just call it `public_html`.
3. You get your symfony app running at `www.myapp.com/web`
4. If you want to ommit the `web` segment, structure your directory like this (and this is encouraged structure):

   ```
   app
   src
   vendor
   public_html
   ```

all in same level.

5. move all  content of `web` directory to `public_html`

The general documentation is already exists: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html

Comment: I find the way in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-kXa73R8Dw thanks